# Total numbers to clear up array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that has several amounts (based on $$$ sales) attached to a 'name' 'id' and 'goal'. As you can see some of the names, id's, and goals are the same. My goal is to gather a total of amounts and attach each total to whichever 'name', 'id', and 'goal' that made the sale. I'm honestly not sure how to go about this as I'm still learning.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [name] => L.Chane [id] => oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 360.00 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [name] => L.Chane [id] => oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 450.00 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [name] => L.Chane [id] => oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 450.00 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [name] => C.James [id] => oper-4c236420-0b11e945 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 370.00 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [name] => C.James [id] => oper-4c236420-0b11e945 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 175.00 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [name] => C.James [id] => oper-4c236420-0b11e945 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 155.00 )
    [6] => Array ( [name] => K.Crass [id] => oper-4c597644-402490ee [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 200.00 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [name] => K.Crass [id] => oper-4c597644-402490ee [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 599.00 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [name] => K.Crass [id] => oper-4c597644-402490ee [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 50.00 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [name] => R.Cervantes [id] => oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 450.00 ) 
   [10] => Array ( [name] => R.Cervantes [id] => oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 589.00 ) 
   [11] => Array ( [name] => R.Cervantes [id] => oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 350.00 ) 
   [12] => Array ( [name] => A.Gerred [id] => oper-4f30019a-27f27473 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 375.00 ) 
   [13] => Array ( [name] => A.Gerred [id] => oper-4f30019a-27f27473 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 294.50 ) 
   [14] => Array ( [name] => A.Gerred [id] => oper-4f30019a-27f27473 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 440.00 ) 
   [15] => Array ( [name] => G.Whitcher [id] => oper-4f300d33-de9592e3 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 5.00 ) 
   [16] => Array ( [name] => G.Whitcher [id] => oper-4f300d33-de9592e3 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 310.00 ) 
   [17] => Array ( [name] => G.Whitcher [id] => oper-4f300d33-de9592e3 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 349.00 ) 
   [18] => Array ( [name] => K.Lawrence [id] => oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 499.00 ) 
   [19] => Array ( [name] => K.Lawrence [id] => oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 187.50 ) 
   [20] => Array ( [name] => K.Lawrence [id] => oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 170.00 ) 
   [21] => Array ( [name] => K.Chane [id] => oper-52657816-3d6516e2 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 375.00 ) 
   [22] => Array ( [name] => K.Chane [id] => oper-52657816-3d6516e2 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 187.50 ) 
   [23] => Array ( [name] => K.Chane [id] => oper-52657816-3d6516e2 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 229.50 ) 
   [24] => Array ( [name] => J.Stewart [id] => oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 170.00 ) 
   [25] => Array ( [name] => J.Stewart [id] => oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 584.00 ) 
   [26] => Array ( [name] => J.Stewart [id] => oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058 [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => 249.50 ) )
```

Here is my code so far (And I know it's not clean, because I'm not using PDO yet, I'm just trying to get it to work):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,u.OperatorName,u.MonthlyGoal
                      FROM tblUserPayments a
                        LEFT JOIN tblOperatorGoals u ON a.OperatorID = u.OperatorID
                      WHERE a.ChargeAmount IS NOT NULL 
                       AND a.PaymentStatus='OK' 
                       AND a.PaymentDate LIKE '$currentDate%' 
                       AND u.MonthlyGoal LIKE '$currentDate%' " );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $operArray[] = array(
  'name' => $row['OperatorName'], 
  'id' => $row['OperatorID'],
  'goal' => $row['MonthlyGoal'], 
  'amount' => $row['ChargeAmount']);
}

foreach ($operArray as $value) {
  if($value['id'] == '' || $value['id'] == null) {
    continue;
  }
  if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $operSums)) {
    $operSums[$value['id']] += $value['amount'];
  } else {
    $operSums[$value['id']] = $value['amount'];
  }
}
```

I'm looking for an array that looks like the following for each operator. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Array ( [name] => BOB [id] => oper-%%%%%%%%%%%%% [goal] => 2014-10-25000 [amount] => $$total$$ )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `GROUP BY` instruction to your SQL query and make the database do it for you, rather than trying to do this in PHP.

E.g. `SELECT SUM(moneys) AS amount FROM mytable GROUP BY username` will take a table with multiple rows for the same username, and collapse all those rows into a single one. The "what do we do with all the data that is different and would be lost?" problem is covered by using "Aggregator" functions. We could count them, or get the min/max values, although in your case you want to use sum, which (predictably) just adds all the values for column `moneys` during the collapse and then yields that number as a new column called `amount`.

Now, with that covered, don't use `mysql_query`.

1. it's insecure and you shouldn't use it, and more importantly
2. it's obsolete and you **can't** use it because modern PHP doesn't actually come with it anymore. Only out-of-date versions of PHP do so if you upgrade, this code will immediately be broken.

Have a look at the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions instead, which are the new, secure, supported mysql connector, or use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) but that's usually silly unless you know your script's going to interface with multiple database formats (like talking to mysql, postgres, and sqlite files)